# MavenProject is null in m2e Maven Project Builder, works fine through Run Configuration and Command Line

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

This is how I inject project property from Maven

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
private MavenProject project;
```

Below code throws IllegallStateException if and only if when built through automatic Eclipse Maven Builder. When I build it Command Line or using defined Run Configuration it's fine.

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    if (project == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

This is how I map lifecycle of custom plugin

```
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.github.fracpete</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>latex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.4.3,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>latex</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Is there any reason why project is null when used through Maven Project Builder m2e but not using Command Line or defined Run Configuration?

Comment: PluginManagement will not execute a plugin never. Furthermore the definition in this way only influences the execution during the import into eclipse or incremental (which means by saving in eclipse)...  Apart from that in which Phase are you executing your plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for attention. This seems like some kind of bug within Eclipse m2e plugin. When I restarted IDE `project` variable stopped to be null and were populated correctly with object. But when I again replace it name (using for instance refactoring from IDE) than again same situation occurred until restart. I forced download snapshot/release each time.
Any way this bug is so minor and irrelevant that I won't waste time to dig it more. Simple restart fix it and field name changes are not-so-often actions.
PS this only happen when `mvn install` same version, so it nuisance only

Comment: when developing, cause release have different versions in pom. Thanks once again for reply.

Comment: As I said only during the initial import those things will be executed.